# How to apply Gabor wavelet to a 3d volume?

Tags: matlab, 3d, volume, wavelet, gabor-filter

I'm looking for a way to apply the Gabor wavelet function to a volume to extract small veins from it.

I've got a 3D Gabor filter creator from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42557-2d-and-3d-gabor-filter-creators).

These are my parameters:

```
gabor3_fwb([1 1], [pi/4 pi/4], 10, 0, 20);
```

Also my image is 150x150x150 double

This is my filter:

[image: Gabor image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your image `image` and your Gabor kernel `kernel`, you simply convolve the two to obtain a filtered image:

```
 result = convn(image, kernel, 'same');
```

Since `kernel` is complex-valued (if it is not, your Gabor generator is wrong), `result` will be complex-valued too. One typically uses the magnitude of the result:

```
result = abs(result);
```